# C++ and VScode integration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Tried my whole day to integrate between vscode and c++ with no success i get output

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.124 seconds
```

in VScode when i try to write c++ code,

My input:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
{
```

I have downloaded VScode and worked through this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

I have created a path as explained in the guide [Where i added the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSqwh.png)
[Inside this i added a new Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHwax.png)

In the command prompt i typed

1. First : pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

in the command prompt when i type
g++ --version
gdb --version

i get this

""g++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.""
In additional i have download the extension in VScode (runner and c++/c

Would like to get help here so i can start using c++ in VScode
I am using windows 10

Comment: The "I get this" part is correct. I don't see anything wrong in your post.

Comment: ***runner*** I recommend you don't use that as it will cause you more confusion when your code is more than 1 source file.

Comment: Try `std::cout << "Hello World!" <<std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem,
I had to delete runner, restart vscode, reinstall runner and restart vscode again, Hope it will help others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Your code gets executed and program shuts itself. If you add getch() that means "Get Character", the program will wait to get a character before exiting
> Note: Include  conio.h when you use getch()

Hope this will solve your problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the same output.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: Placing a breakpoint is a better alternative to changing the code under test.

Comment: I don't think this was the problem but it was not a great question because it did not explain the problem that well.